# accord de "se libérer" selon l'emploi

Tags: accord, verbes-pronominaux

Comment accorder avec le verbe "se libérer" dans un emploi transitif ?

J'aurais tendance à vouloir écrire : "C'est l'heure que je me suis libérée.", même si je suis un homme.

Et il s'agit de signifier "Je me suis libéré la deuxième heure de la matinée" où le groupe est initialement COD et le sujet fait l'action.

Alors que j'écrirais plutôt "C'est l'heure à laquelle je me suis libéré." qui ne signifie pas la même chose et où j'accorderais aussi mais cette fois avec le sujet.

Comment: Bizarre, mais pas de problème, je ferais les mêmes accords, bien que l'auxiliaire soit _être_ dans le premier cas. Intéressant, je suis curieux de voir ce que vont dire les autres membres de FSE.

Comment: C'est *à cette heure* que j'ai été libre. Une heure compte le temps qui passe et ne sait faire rien d'autre, ce n'est pas elle qui emprisonne non plus, elle n'a pas de menottes. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Les accords présentés dans la question sont corrects:

1. *C'est l'heure que je me suis libérée* : J'ai libéré quoi ? Une heure.
2. *C'est l'heure à laquelle je me suis libéré(e)* : J'ai libéré qui ? Moi (à une heure donnée).

On aurait pu aussi dire: *C'est l'heure où je me suis libéré(e).*

Comment: La réponse 1 sonne mal pour la francophonie ‘officielle’: « C'est *à cette* heure que je me suis libéré(e) » ou « C'est l'heure que *j'ai* libérée [sur *mon* emploi du temps] » — sinon ce sera « C l'heure qu'je m'suis libéré [pour aller au ciné] » … une simple question de circonstances et d'usages régionaux ou d'approximations orthographiques calligraphiées différemment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

La règle pour les accords des verbes pronominaux avec l'auxiliaire être est la suivante :

- si le verbe est intransitif (pas de complément d'objet direct) l'accord se fait avec le sujet :

> Elle s'est faite toute seule

- si le verbe est transitif, le participe passé ne s'accorde pas. Sauf si le COD est placé avant le verbe auquel cas l'accord se fait avec le COD.

> Elle s'est fait une tasse de café

mais

> J'ai apprécié la tasse de café que mon père m'a faite.

Les accords sont donc corrects tous les deux.